# Telnet disable sending each character

Tags: windows, telnet

I am writing a simple telnet server, it works perfectly when I run telnet from Debian and Ubuntu machines, but when I connect from my windows computer, it sends each keypress as if I had hit enter. I can't seem to fix it, anyone know what to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "as if I had hit enter".  Please edit your question to describe the troublesome behaviour in more detail.  (Some code might also be useful.)

Comment: Oops, I could have been more clear there. In a linux terminal, if I were to type "help" and send that, the server would receive it all as one string, while when I do it on my windows telnet client, it sends the strings "h", "e", "l", and "p" seperately. I don't think the server code is the issue, as the problem only persists my windows laptop, but not when using  an Ubuntu VM or a remote Debian server. (I haven't tried any other windows computers.) I think I have setting enabled that I need to disable, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The telnet protocol [RFC854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854) says that data "should" be accumulated in the host until a complete line of data is ready for transmission, but I don't think this is a strict requirement.  It wouldn't surprise me if the (fairly primitive) Windows client ignores this and sends each keystroke separately.  Since a single line of data might sometimes be broken up into two pieces by the network layer anyway, I *think* your server needs to collect data until it sees an ENTER key.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [RFC858](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc858) and [RFC1184](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1184)